# Custom FormBuilder super class is a SafeBuffer. What am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So, I have a custom form builder. It works except for when I want to override superclass methods.

When I do the following:

```
class MyFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def number_field(value, options = {})
    super.number_field(value, options)
  end
end
```

and call

```
'f.number_field(:value)'
```

on my form, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `number_field' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007f9a44b762f0>
```

I have called

```
raise "class: #{super.class}"
```

inside number field and I get:

class: ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer

So the error is arising from my overridden method. Other methods that don't call super class methods work fine in my form builder. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try just calling `super` without the arguments.

This will call ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder's version of the method with the same arguments passed to the original call.

But if you want to actually override the method, you need to provide your own code. Try something like:

```
class MyFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def number_field(value, options = {})
    "foo"
  end
end
```

And see if calling `f.number_field(:value)` prints out `foo`.

Then start replacing the guts of your number_field method with whatever you really want to do.